# Yandex Translator Api using to vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, yandex, yandex-api

find YandexTranslator in here : https://github.com/prokhor-ozornin/Yandex.NET.Translator

I installed YandexTranslator via Nuget

This iy my code in button translate:

IYandexTranslator translator = Yandex.Translator(api => api.ApiKey(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApiKey"]).Format(ApiDataFormat.Json));
    IEnumerable translationPairs = translator.TranslationPairs(); //error The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
    string language = translator.Detect("This is English text");
    ITranslation translation = translator.Translate("ru", "To be translated to Russian");

How to convert VB.net

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim translator As IYandexTranslator = Yandex.Translator(Function(api)api.ApiKey(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ApiKey")).Format(ApiDataFormat.Json))
Dim translationPairs As IEnumerable = translator.TranslationPairs
//error The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
Dim language As String = translator.Detect("This is English text")
Dim translation As ITranslation = translator.Translate("ru", "To be translated to Russian")
```